# How to switch to sprite images while keeping existing transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a site on which I'm currently not using sprites to store images in. Instead, I'm directly referencing individual images. I now want to put all static images in a single sprite to optimize my site.

Currently, I'm using the `transition: background-image 0.5s;` CSS effect for hovered images. This results in a nice looking 'fading' effect, when the mouse hovers.

**JSFiddle showing two examples where this fading transition effect happens:** http://jsfiddle.net/VsVpU/

The problem is that if I use sprites, `background-image` has to change to `background-position`, and this changes the effect from the previous fading effect, to a vertical/horizontal sliding effect.

How can I switch to sprites, while keeping the existing fading transition effect, **and NOT changing the source HTML** ?

I don't want to change the HTML because that will result in a LOT of changes. Can this be achieved using only CSS ? Or using CSS + jQuery/JavaScript ? .. Although I'd like to avoid JavaScript too here, if possible ..

EDIT:

The solution should be cross-browser compatible too ..

Comment: It nothing affect your old styles just go for it by Sprites using CascadeSS.. :)

Comment: Didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 sprite images, one for the normal state and another one for the hover state.

The coordinates of a particular element background **must be** the same in both images.

Then, the transition from normal state to hover state is done in the image url, but not in the coordinates